# Does Child Cgroup automatically get deleted if there are no processes running under it

Tags: linux, process, cgroups

I created a child cgroup under parent cgroup and running processes periodically under child. However after sometime, I see that the child cgroup automatically gets deleted.
What could be the reason ?
Any config while creating child cgroup that tells not to delete the cgroup, even if there are no processes attached to it for quite a long time ?

Answer (score 0):

I remember that it comes as "/sbin/rmmod" by default, I think the code I gave below will not delete any group you will create from now on.

```
echo "" > /sys/fs/cgroup/release_agent
```

I hope it works

Comment: @mbravo - Is child cgroup deleted ? what is the duration after which the child cgroup gets deleted if there is no process running under it ?

Comment: I couldn't remember, but I did some research, it was deleted after the last process on it.